# How does this hierarchy/inheritance between multiple classes work in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, hierarchy, multiple-inheritance

I had this question in a test, and I'm trying to develop some understanding here on how this thing works, I'm pretty sure no one code like this, but just for my understanding and tests to come, given this code and subquest I was asked to put in comment some of the lines.

a. What would be the output if we comment #1 #3

b. "" "" #2 #3

c. #1 #4

d. #1 #4 #5 #9

e. #1 #3 #5 #8 #9 #10

f. #1 #3 #5 #6 #7 #9

also I started with not commenting anything and it seems like the pass statements do not change anything at all (between it and quest a)

```
class A(object):
    pass                          #1
    def __init__(self):           #2
        print(" 1 ", end="")      #2


class B(A):
    pass                          #3
    def __init__(self):           #4
        super().__init__()        #4
        print(" 2 ", end="")      #4


class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        #5
        print(" 3 ", end="")


class D(C, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        #6
        A().__init__()            #7
        print(" 4 ", end="")


class E(D, A):
    def __init__(self):           #8
        super().__init__()        #9
        print(" 5 ", end="")      #10


e = E()
```

Well I'd like to know if some1 can give any tips/ graphical view of how to understand this thing about the multiple inheritance

** I tried debug it and see where it jump everytime, and I don't get it, why does it go at class D on A().**init** () twice?
and what does super()**init** does on a class that inherit from object

since if I change a-little by adding new class

```
class F(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()       # Comment and uncomment this
        print(" F ", end="")
```

and make C class inherit it C(F)

then the output changes whether I comment super line in F or not
like if I comment it, it doesn't go to B class when it returns to D class..

Comment: I think you can conclude from your own test that the `pass` has no effect. As far as inheritance goes, I suggest you read about method resolution order (MRO) to get some background on pythons inheritance model.

Comment: Yeah the pass indeed not changing anything, I'll look about the MRO hopefully this clear some stuff for me

Comment: Biggest issue for me right now is that I don't understand why it go twice to A class on the A.__init__() command when it return back to class D

Comment: Look in the `__init__` for  `D`. Comment the lines out one at a time to see the effect.

Comment: Alright I've managed to understand quite most of the things and why A().__init__ occur two times - one time for creation of A() which automatically calls init and second time just explicitly calling the init func. Tho I still not really understand why in class E(D,A): it doesn't go to A when it finish all the travel in D